# In Python: How do I print the elements as a string from a text file the same way as it appears in the file?

Tags: python, string, file

I've a file name data.txt which have:

```
First, Last, GPA, Major, Drops
Jane, Doe, 3.5, CS, 2
Joe, Doe, 2.0  , CpE, 0
Todd,Brown,3.88,CS,5
Mike,Smith,   3.88   , CS  , 5
```

I've to print a table from the file which will look like:

```
First, Last, GPA, Major, Drops
Jane, Doe, 3.5, CS, 2
Joe, Doe, 2.0, CpE, 0
Todd, Brown, 3.88, CS, 5
Mike, Smith, 3.88, CS, 5
```

My code is so far:

```
fp = open('data.txt','r')
str1 = ""
for line in fp:
    a = line.strip().replace("   ", " ").replace("   ,", ",")
    str1 += str(a) + '\n'
fp.close()
print(str1)
```

What I'm struggling with the spacing. The text from the file has excessive spacing or lack of spaces. Example: For the last line, I want to print like:

```
Mike, Smith, 3.88, CS, 5
```

But it appears in the text from the file:

```
Mike,Smith,   3.88   , CS  , 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, `split` the line then `strip` the space and then `join` `list` with comma and sapce.

```
with open('test1.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        a = [item.strip() for item in line.split(',')]
        print ', '.join(a)
```

Or you may use `map` function as well

```
a = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
```

Output:-

```
First, Last, GPA, Major, Drops
Jane, Doe, 3.5, CS, 2
Joe, Doe, 2.0, CpE, 0
Todd, Brown, 3.88, CS, 5
Mike, Smith, 3.88, CS, 5
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use dictionaries for this problem.

Comment: @ZihanI. i didn't use dictionary here.

Comment: @ZihanI.if you find answer helping and correct please mark correct and pramote me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string based on white space and then rejoin it with one space

```
fp.close()
str1 = ' '.join(str1.split())
print(str1)
```